# Nested functions scope in Python

Tags: python, tree

I have the following function that walks a nested tree and prints the result

```
def walk_tree(tree):   
    def read_node(node):
        print node
        for n in node['subnodes']:
            read_node(n)
    read_node(tree)
```

If I want to return a txt with the data collected from walking the tree, thought that the following would have worked:

```
def walk_tree(tree):
    txt = ''  
    def read_node(node):
        txt += node
        for n in node['subnodes']:
            read_node(n)
    read_node(tree)
```

But `txt` doesn't seem to be in `read_node`'s scope. Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`txt` is accessible in `read_node`, I think it's just some problem with `+=` and that `txt` is not in local scope in `read_node`.

```
>>> def a():
...  x = ""
...  def b():
...   x += "X"
...  b()
...  print x
... 
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in a
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in b
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def a():
...  x = []
...  def b():
...   x.append("X")
...  b()
...  print "".join(x)
... 
>>> a()
X
```

You should use list and `"".join(...)` instead of `str += ...` anyways.

Answer (score 5):

In Python you cannot rebind variables of an outer scope (of `walk_tree` in your example).

So this will fail:

```
def a():
    def b():
        txt += "b" # !!!

        print txt

    txt = "mytext"
    b()

a()
```

but this will work:

```
def a():
    def b():
        # removed assignment: txt += "b"

        print txt

    txt = "mytext"
    b()

a()
```

So you may want to avoid rebinding:

```
def a():
    def b():
        obj["key"] = "newtext"

    obj = {"key" : "mytext"}
    b()

a()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
def walk_tree(tree):
    txt = ''  # (1)
    def read_node(node, txt=txt):
        txt += node # (2)
        for n in node['subnodes']:
            read_node(n, txt)
    read_node(tree)
```

This binds `walk_tree`s value of txt to the default value in `read_node`, which should persist (if my grasp of Python theory is correct).

Comment: This won't work because strings are immutable in Python, so `txt += node` will create a new string instead of changing the existing one.